# module 'NFS' was not loaded error in powershell for Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, nfs

Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter on EC2

I tried following [this guide to deploy NFS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574143.aspx)

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads> Import-Module ServerManager
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads> Add-WindowsFeature FS-NFS-Services

Success Restart Needed Exit Code Feature Result
------- -------------- --------- --------------
True    No             NoChan... {}

PS C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads> Import-Module NFS
Import-Module : The specified module 'NFS' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module
directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module NFS
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (NFS:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

How can I get this cmdlet installed?

Comment: Is it possible that you needed to start a new PowerShell session and then it would have access to the module?

Comment: @Matt I tried a new shell and same issue.